# Unable to use hidden field value in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, url-parameters, ognl

I have a hidden field whose value I want to send to my action, but it always sends `null`.

```
<s:hidden property="SystemId" name="SystemId" id="SystemId" value="1"/>
```

I am calling the action like this

```
<s:url  id="papa" value="Alertpup?ET_ID=%{ID}&ET_BUSID=%{SystemId}"></s:url>
<s:a href="%{papa}"><s:property value="ID" /></s:a>
```

But my `ET_BUSID` field in from bean will be `null`.

Comment: Seems like you are not understanding what hidden fields are. See http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/tagpages/i/inputhidden.htm or http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmlhidden.php.

Comment: @Roman C                                                                             **ok this works, but i want to change the value of the variable sometimes so i have a js like this**                                          ' function setSystemID(ID)
 {
  alert("hi");
  document.forms[0].currentSystemId.value = ID;
  alert(document.forms[0].currentSystemId.value);
 } '

Comment: @BaN3 If you're submitting a form then why put the value in the URL?

Comment: @BaN3 No, you can't. You want mess up javascript with java.

Comment: @Dave No im not submitting the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of hidden try with

```
<s:set name="SystemId" value="1"/>
<s:url  id="papa" value="Alertpup?ET_ID=%{ID}&ET_BUSID=%{#SystemId}"/>
```